# Displaying tables in C++ console window

Tags: c++, tabular

```
cout<<"  Name\t"
    <<"Cat\t"
    <<"Barcode\t"
    <<"Price\t"
    <<"Manufa\t"
    <<"Stock\t"
    <<"Sold\t"
    <<"ExDate\t "
    <<"Disc"<<endl;
for (unsigned int i=0; i < _storage.size(); i++)
{
    cout <<i <<":";
    _storage[i]->showData();
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I am trying to display  data in a aligned manner.I am currently using the `t` character to do this but this will result in a misalignment if the data in one of the variable is too long.

How do I properly display data in a table form in C++?

Comment: By MS-DOS, do you mean console?

Comment: @user1203499: MS-DOS is an ancient operating system, the console is a window that allow the user to interact with command-line interface applications.

Comment: @user1203499: MS-DOS is an operating system from the 80's that few people are using anymore.  If you aren't aware of the difference, I doubt you're one of those people.  A console is a window with a text interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `setfill` and `setw` to set the fill char and width of the columns. The problem is you are going to have to limit the columns for it to look right.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `std::setw` to set string width:

`std::cout << std::setw (5) << "ASM" << std::endl;`

So instead of using tabs, pad your string to a sufficiently large length.